# Validation on fields using index position

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-validation

I have a couple of fields that I would like to replicate dynamically. I'm using ng-reapt which is doing the job. However, the validation messages are not working. Here's what I've got:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>teste</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='testController'>
        <label>Number of Workers</label>
        <select ng-model="quantity" ng-change="changed()">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

        <form name='frm' action='/workers/add' method='POST'>
            <div ng-repeat="i in numberOfWorkers track by $index">{{$index + 1}}
                <div>
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input class="fullSize" letters-only placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="workers[$index].firstName" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="50" ng-required="true" maxlength="50">
                    <span ng-cloak class="error-container" ng-show="submitted || showErrors(frm.firstName)">
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.firstName[{{$index}}].$error.required">* Please enter your name.</small>
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.firstName[{{$index}}].$error.minlength">* At least 3 chars.</small>
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.firstName[{{$index}}].$error.maxlength">* No more than 50 chars.</small>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Surname</label>
                    <input class="fullSize" letters-only placeholder="Please enter your surname" type="text" name="surName" ng-model="workers[$index].surName" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="50" ng-required="true" maxlength="50">
                    <span ng-cloak class="error-container" ng-show="submitted || showErrors(frm.surName)">
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.surName[$index].$error.required">* Please enter your name.</small>
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.surName[$index].$error.minlength">* At least 3 chars.</small>
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.surName[$index].$error.maxlength">* No more than 50 chars.</small>
                    </span>                 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input class="grid-full" placeholder="Please enter your e-mail" type="email" name="email" ng-model="workers[$index].email" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="50" required maxlength="50">
                    <span class="error-container" ng-show="submitted || showErrors(frm.email)">
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.email[$index].$error.required">* Please enter your E-mail.</small>
                        <small class="error" ng-show="frm.email[$index].$error.email">* Invalid email.</small>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>

        <button ng-click="test()">test</button>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("app",[]);
            app.controller('testController',['$scope', function($scope){

                $scope.quantity = 1;
                $scope.submitted = false;
                $scope.numberOfWorkers = [1];
                $scope.workers = [];

                $scope.getNumber = function (num) {
                    return new Array(num);
                };

                $scope.test = function(){

                    console.log($scope.workers);
                };

                $scope.changed = function() {
                  $scope.workers = [];
                  $scope.numberOfWorkers = new Array(parseInt($scope.quantity));
                }


                $scope.isUndefined = function (thing) {
                    var thingIsUndefined = (typeof thing === "undefined");

                    return thingIsUndefined;
                };

                $scope.showErrors = function (field) {
                    var fieldIsUndefined = $scope.isUndefined(field);

                    if (fieldIsUndefined == false)
                    {
                        var stateInvalidIsUndefined = $scope.isUndefined(field.$invalid);
                        var stateDirtyIsUndefined = $scope.isUndefined(field.$dirty);

                        return (fieldIsUndefined == false && stateInvalidIsUndefined == false && stateDirtyIsUndefined == false &&
                            (field.$invalid && field.$dirty));
                    }
                    return false;
                };

            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to display and validate fields using the index position?

```
frm.firstName.$error.minlength
```

The code above works for the first block, but it display the message to all copies.

Comment: Just a pointer, you can try setting `ID` dynamically using `$index` and process accordingly.

Comment: There'se no way to use just the name attribute?

Comment: Since you are running in loop, you will have multiple elements with same name and you will have to write extra code just to handle it. Another way could be, create a validate function and pass `$index` as a parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this along the lines of what you're trying to achieve:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HVwnRfvt30WrsteY6DvW

We need to assign a dynamic `name` to each input field, by way of using the `$index` of the `ngRepeat`:

```
<form name="form">
    <div ng-repeat="entry in array track by $index">
        <input type="text" name="someField{{$index}}">
    <div>
</form>
```

And based on the number of entries in `array`, we can access in a loop each dynamically created `someField` using the syntax below:

```
form['someField' + $index]
```

In your case, let's say we have three workers, and the second worker's `firstName` is invalid -- in an `ngRepeat`, it would look like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in numberOfWorkers track by $index">
    isValid? --> form.firstName{{$index}}.$valid = {{form['firstName' + $index].$valid}}
  </div>
```

**Output**:

```
isValid? --> form.firstName0.$valid = true
isValid? --> form.firstName1.$valid = false
isValid? --> form.firstName2.$valid = true
```